# How do I reset the SMTP login and password of the Email Notifier in Teamcity

Tags: email, teamcity

I'm trying to set up email notification for our Teamcity server (v9.0.1). During some trial and error I entered smtp login and smtp password, and saved. The problem is that the smtp-server I'm supposed to use does not require a login and password, so I would like to set these fields to empty.

I am able to remove the login and password, and successfully test my connection, but if I press save, the page reloads, and the login and password are reset back to the previous value. Please see the attached image.

**TLDR:** I want to remove the values of the yellow fields in the image below.

[image: Image of email notification in Teamcity]

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more trial and error, I discovered that this was browser specific.

I use the latest version of Opera, which auto-filled the fields. Changing to another browser fixed the error.

Comment: I had the same problem with Chrome auto-fill. Using Firefox instead did the trick.